# Retrieve parent html element from a text

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I have an application (made in [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org)) by which I can retrieve HTML data. Within the received HTML I have to retrieve a particular element by looking up some text (say 'Total amount').

The target element is the parent element where the 'Total amount' is situated.  It may be inside a `div` or inside a `table`. The tag will be unkown to the application.

How do I retrieve this element using either C# or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get all the elements whose immediate text contains 'Total amount', the `:contains('')` selector won't help you as it will return all the elements in the upper hierarchy of the actual element.
Try this **JQuery** code:

```
$('body *').each(function() {
    if($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().indexOf("Total amount") > -1) {
        // $(this) has your desired text as it's immediate text, so use it here
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/y00d1n5u/1/
Above code iterates over all the elements inside the `body` tag, strips each element's children and searches the remaining text for the search string.